# SQL Server temporary index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that the execution path shows would work faster with an index.

Before I request the table index, I would like to create a temporary index to see if it's actually worth having as a permanent solution, or if it's a false flag, and the time would be better spent looking at some other part of the query to speed it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as temporary index. You either create an index or not.

All calculations and maintenance related to an index has to be done even if it is considered as temporary, I don't see any reason to have a feature like this.

Create the index, then drop it if it does not help.

Keep in mind, that the missing index recommendations are not always the best. They are scoped to the query and (almost) always suggesting a covering index. Using all of these suggestions will lead to duplicated and overlapping indexes, and thus performance degradation (mostly for write operations) and unnecessary disk usage.